# How does the transform method transFigure place my text?

Tags: matplotlib, transform

I have problems understanding the different transforms for text position in a Matplotlib plot. There exist three predefined transforms:

`ax.transData`, `ax.transAxes`, `fig.transFigure`

When I have the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(facecolor='lightgray')
ax.axis([0, 10, 0, 10])
ax.text(1, 5, ". Data: (1, 5)", transform=ax.transData)
ax.text(0.2, 0.2, ". Figure: (0.2, 0.2)", transform=fig.transFigure)
```

I don't understand the fourth line. First problem: what is the figsize in my plot?

I checked the docstring of `plt.figure` and there it says that default figsize is 6.4 (width in inches) and 4.8 (height in inches). But when I use `fig.get_figwidth` and `fig.get_figheight` I see that width is 6.0 and width 4.0. Why?
Assuming figsize is (6, 4):
The text should appear at 20% of figsize (x-coordinate) and 20% of figsize (y-coordinate).
Is that correct?

Comment: Have you read the [Transformations Tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html)?

Comment: default figure dimensions are given by [your rc file](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html) you can check you default by running `print(matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I checked the docstring of plt.figure and there it says that default figsize is 6.4 (width in inches) and 4.8 (height in inches).

Indeed, you can check [the source code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/b12c761608d5c00eb66613b4335717bfb751884e/lib/matplotlib/rcsetup.py#L1325), where it says `[6.4, 4.8]`.

> But when I use fig.get_figwidth and fig.get_figheight I see that width is 6.0 and width 4.0. Why?

Because either you, the interpreter you use, or another library you have loaded has changed those settings.

> Assuming figsize is (6, 4): The text should appear at 20% of figsize (x-coordinate) and 20% of figsize (y-coordinate). Is that correct?

Yes, that is correct. Coordinates start from bottom left of the figure.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @ImportanceOfBeingErnest for this nice visualization!